# MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line) when installing scikits-samplerate

Tags: python, python-2.7, header, pycharm, scikits

I tried the pip installation through pycahrm but it came up with the following error:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: SRC (http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/)library not found.  Directories to search
for the libraries can be specified in the site.cfg file, in section
[samplerate].
```

So then I went to the link given and downloaded the needed files.
I ran the installation again and got the same error.

I went here: http://cournape.github.io/audiolab/installing.html#download

And found out: "...you need to create a file site.cfg to set the location of libsndfile and its header (there are site.cfg examples which should give you an idea how to use them on your platform)."

After I dowloaded the module from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.samplerate, (I checked the example in notepad++ all it said was: '[samplerate]')I created file this is what put in it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile
```

I did the python setup.py install and recieved the following error:

```
raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
```

Config.parser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains section headers.
C:\...\site.cfg, line 1
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile

What headers is it looking for?
How do I fix this error so that I can install scikts-samplerate?

Comment: I am running a Windows 8 (64 bit)

Comment: You should specify the library location as well as the include files location.  Not very helpful for windows, but please look here for reference... [link](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2008-November/018842.html)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** (5 min after this post): follow my guide below OR save yourself this whole ordeal and download an unofficial build for Windows from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.samplerate
...Works just as well. You can install this `.whl` package by running `pip install scikits.samplerate-0.3.3-cp27-none-[win32|win_amd64].whl` in a terminal with admin rights.

**Original Post**

Is this still an open issue? Because I seem to have found the solution:

- download libsamplerate (to `C:\libsamplerate`) and compile (very complicated in itself, but I managed to do it with a lot of hacking in Visual Studio 2015 Community). If this step is unclear, answer or comment and I will provide more detailed steps.
- after compilation you end up with 3 new files in the libsamplerate folder, `libsamplerate-0.dll`, `libsamplerate-0.lib` & `libsamplerate-0.exp`
- in your libsamplerate directory, create 2 new subfolders, called `lib` and `include`
- copy the 3 new files into `lib` and rename them removing the "-0" at the end, so that they are called `libsamplerate.dll`, etc.
- copy the samplerate.h from the libsamplerate/src folder into the new libsamplerate/include
- that's it for the libsamplerate
- now download [scikits.samplerate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.samplerate) (the .tar.gz file on the right side)
- unpack somewhere (place doesn't matter)
- go into the directory of the unpacked scikits.samplerate
- open the file site.cfg in a text editor
- remove everything and put this text inside:

  ```
  [samplerate]
  library_dirs = C:/libsamplerate/lib
  include_dirs = C:/libsamplerate/include
  ```
- save file and close
- open cmd/terminal (ideally as administrator)
- `cd` into the directory of scikits.samplerate
- run `python setup.py install`
- jump around your room in excitement

Comment: I followed your steps very carefully but always end up like this: http://pastebin.com/HfsW4urh (Python3.5, Win x64, MSVC 2015)
Any ideas on that would be helpful!

Comment: @sonovice: The problem in your case is most likely the linker. Check line 52 of your output where it says `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'samplerate.lib'`. 

Do I correctly assume that you have a file called `libsamplerate.lib` in the folder `C:/libsamplerate/lib/`? If the answer is yes, try making a copy of it and renaming the copy `samplerate.lib`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your suggestion, but the linker is definitely looking for another samplerate.lib. Here is my output in a slightly more readable version: http://pastebin.com/ZAx7FtC4
I am not a C Guru, so no clue what I should try next.

Comment: @sonovice I'm having a hard time reproducing the error. Could you please zip up the folder `C:\libsamplerate\`, upload the zip somewhere, and then post the link here?

Comment: Thank you for your patience so far. I've uploaded it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfmbxl6qgqirn0l/libsamplerate.zip?dl=1

Comment: @sonovice Give this a try please: https://www.dropbox.com/s/csn9so7ejwybb2n/libsamplerate-mod.zip?dl=1

(Just unpack and overwrite your current `C:\libsamplerate\` folder. I didn't change a lot, I just copied some files around, to make sure the linker can find the library. I'm not super sure this works, but it should at least give us a different error.)